# Unable to packaging android project

Tags: android

I just deleted one of the image resource from my project which was not used anywhere and tried to run the project but getting error "Error generating final archive: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\xxx\bin\resources.ap_ does not exist error."

Comment: check your project configuration

Comment: Everything is fine in project configuration nothing is changed there!!!!

Comment: I am not so sure. Why would you need 4 exclamation marks then...

Comment: ok sorry, it would be better if i get answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse you can try:

**Project** -> **Clean** -> Then select your project and click **OK**.

Comment: I tried to clean project but still it getting same error.